# Divide a normalized value into three equal values mathematically

Tags: javascript, math

I have a value between 0 and 1.

```
let t = 0;
```

I want to divide this value into three variables.

```
let a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;

if (t < 0.3) {
    a = t / 0.3;
} else {
    a = 1;
    if (t < 0.6) {
      b = (t - 0.3) / 0.3;
    } else {
        b = 1;
        c = (t - 0.6) / 0.3;
    }
}
```

Is there a shorter mathematical way to do this?

Comment: *"I want to divide this value into three variables"* Using what rules? Your calculation above isn't obviously anything one's familiar with...? In particular, the `a = t / 0.3` and leaving `b` and `c` set to `0` when `t < 0.3` is true seems...odd.

Comment: Although the question is not extremely well worded, it looks clear what they want from the given code!

Comment: You can do it without using `if` statements, using `Math.min()`.
`a = Math.min(t/0.3, 1);
b = Math.max(Math.min((t-0.3)/0.3, 1), 0);
c = Math.max(Math.min((t-0.6)/0.3, 1), 0);`

Comment: With `if` statements, I think it would be cleared if you separate into three clean cases and always assign all three variables:  `if (t < 0.3) {
    a = t/0.3;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;
} else if (t < 0.6) {
    a = 1;
    b = (t - 0.3) / 0.3;
    c = 0;
} else {
    a = 1;
    b = 1;
    c = (t - 0.6) / 0.3;
}`

Comment: @Stef you could skip the `b = 0; c = 0;`  since they default to `0`. Also, this is not mathematical as OP asked.

Comment: @adiga My point was that the code is easier to read by not skipping those statements. It is easier to see "in this case, here are the three values for a,b,c" than "in this case, here is the value for a and b; about the value of c, I'll let you look up and search whether it might have been attributed a value in another branch of this cascaded if"

Comment: @Stef fair point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a separate `allocate` function to allocate `t` over the 3 variables:

```
function allocate(t, min, den) {
  return t <= min ? 0 : den <= t - min ? 1 : (t-min) / den;
}

let a = allocate(t, 0.0, 0.3);
let b = allocate(t, 0.3, 0.3);
let c = allocate(t, 0.6, 0.3);
```

In case `c` is defined to hold all "remaining" values of `t>0.9`, in which case `c` may exceed 1, then:

```
let c = Math.max(0, (t - 0.6) / 0.3);
```

Answer (score 0):

### With `if, else if, else`

I think the code would be more readable if you cleanly separate the three cases, and assign values to a,b,c inside every case. Not assigning a variable and relying on its default value makes the code harder to understand, because the reader will need to look up and make sure the value wasn't changed since its initialization.

```
if (t < 0.3) {
    a = t/0.3;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;
} else if (t < 0.6) {
    a = 1;
    b = (t - 0.3) / 0.3;
    c = 0;
} else {
    a = 1;
    b = 1;
    c = (t - 0.6) / 0.3;
}
```

### With `min()` and `max()`

If you want, you can do it without using `if` statements, using `Math.min()`.

```
a = Math.min(t/0.3, 1);
b = Math.max(Math.min((t-0.3)/0.3, 1), 0);
c = Math.max(Math.min((t-0.6)/0.3, 1), 0);
```

### With ternary operators

```
a = (t < 0.3) ? (t / 0.3) : 1;
b = (t < 0.3) ? 0 : (t < 0.6) ? (t - 0.3) / 0.3 : 1;
c = (t < 0.6) ? 0 : (t - 0.3) / 0.3;
```

I personally dislike this solution because:

1. it makes the code less readable because the values are disseminated amongst a plethora of symbols;
2. it performs more tests than necessary since every `?` is basically a hidden `if`.

Comment: Thanks! I removed that bullet point, as well as most of the parentheses.